# How do you say 'to add to'?

Tags: word-choice, words

How would you say:

> A further ¥2000 will be added to your bill.

Is it:

> お会計に追加２０００円は付けられます。

Comment: A possible formal expression could be `追加料金`, which means `additional fee` (but notice that it doesn't apply to all scenarios)

Comment: Do you want to sound polite/formal (like a shop clerk would say to a customer), or casual? (かかります would not sound very polite. We have more formal/polite ways to say that)

Answer (score 3):

A further ¥2000 will be added to your bill. would usually be said as
 あと￥２０００かかります。 or more politely, お会計はあと¥2000かかります。

Source : experience