# How to say 'to add'

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I know this is a quite general question, but I've been wondering what are the differet ways to say 'to add'. 'To add' is a very useful word for everyday use, but I find it quite tricky to find the correct japanese equivalent since there are diffenret words for different circumstances. What I mean by this:

- 二つの数字を**足す**。To add two numbers together.
- 塩を**加える**。 To add salt.

- あと2000円**かかります**。[2000¥ will be added to your bill](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39389/how-do-you-say-to-add-to).
- もう一つ**付け加えます**。[To add (to that).](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56361/how-to-say-just-to-add-to-that-in-a-meeting)

There is also　'追加する'　and　'加算する' , which I'm not sure how to use.

1. How do I use '追加する'　and　'加算す'?
2. Are there any different ways to say 'to add'?
3. What are the differences between them? (Please show on a sentence.)

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with abstract numbers in mathematics, , use "加算する".
Other uncountable numbers, specific amounts, or any numbers in everyday life, use "加える" or the simpler "足す".